# about dll: does A-NAME-d.dll has anything to do with A-NAME.dll?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2017

When I run a project from VS, I got prompt:

> VCOMP120D.dll was not found.

But all google search result was `VCOMP120.dll`.

Do these 2 dll has anything to do with each other? And where do I find this dll?

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft DLLs, the 'D' suffix means "Debug".

The Debug DLLs should be found just fine within Visual Studio, but when you start installing on other PCs they won't be found.  And Microsoft does not permit you to distribute copies.  Instead, you must switch your build to "Release" mode, then your application will run without the "D" version of the DLL.